# Flattening multidimensional JSON in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a JSON which looks like this,

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "displayName": "Sharad Dutta",
      "givenName": "",
      "surname": "",
      "extension_user_type": "user",
      "identities": [
        {
          "signInType": "emailAddress",
          "issuerAssignedId": "kkr007@gmail.com"
        }
      ],
      "extension_timezone": "VET",
      "extension_locale": "en-GB",
      "extension_tenant": "EG12345"
    },   
    {
      "displayName": "Sharad Dutta",
      "givenName": "",
      "surname": "",
      "extension_user_type": "user",
      "identities": [
        {
          "signInType": "emailAddress",
          "issuerAssignedId": "kkr007@gmail.com"
        }
      ],
      "extension_timezone": "VET",
      "extension_locale": "en-GB",
      "extension_tenant": "EG12345"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am writing a Java code where I am parsing this Multidimensional JSON to FLAT JSON. If you look closely, the JSON is wrapped in a **"users"** wrapper and then has couple of users as objects. For each user, there is a field called **"identifiers"** which is again a wrapper.

I want to flat this JSON, I have written a code but it is leaving  a JSON blob for identifiers, for non nested it is working fine

```
JSONObject output;
        try {
            output = new JSONObject(userJsonAsString);
            JSONArray docs = output.getJSONArray("users");
            System.out.println(docs);
```

This is giving me below output, however i still have to flat inner wrapper "identifiers"

```
[
  {
    "extension_timezone": "VET",
    "extension_tenant": "EG12345",
    "extension_locale": "en-GB",
    "identities": [
      {
        "signInType": "emailAddress",
        "issuerAssignedId": "pdhongade007@gmail.com"
      }
    ],
    "displayName": "Sharad Dutta",
    "surname": "",
    "givenName": "",
    "extension_user_type": "user"
  },
  {
    "extension_timezone": "VET",
    "extension_tenant": "EG12345",
    "extension_locale": "en-GB",
    "identities": [
      {
        "signInType": "userName",
        "issuerAssignedId": "pdhongade007"
      }
    ],
    "displayName": "Wayne Rooney",
    "surname": "Rooney",
    "givenName": "Wayne",
    "extension_user_type": "user"
  }
]
```

This is what I need,

```
{
    "extension_timezone": "VET",
    "extension_tenant": "EG12345",
    "extension_locale": "en-GB",
    "signInType": "emailAddress",
    "issuerAssignedId": "pdhongade007@gmail.com",
    "displayName": "Sharad Dutta",
    "surname": "",
    "givenName": "",
    "extension_user_type": "user"
  }
```

I have to then parse this to CSV, which I know how, I just need to flat this further. Any help will be appreciated. I tried looking around, but a lot of them were using external dependencies.

//UPDATE

```
{
  "extension_timezone": "VET",
  "extension_tenant": "EG12345",
  "extension_locale": "en-GB",
  "signInType": "userName",
  "displayName": "Wayne Rooney",
  "surname": "Rooney",
  "givenName": "Wayne",
  "issuerAssignedId": "pdhongade007",
  "extension_user_type": "user"
}
```

When I tried @Jakub solution, I am getting the flat JSON, however it is not iterating for all the users. Just one!(I am guessing the last user only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below approach, this will give you a  comma separated format for both user and identifier (flat file per se),

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, ParseException {
    
            String userJsonFile = "path to your JSON";
            final StringBuilder sBuild = new StringBuilder();
            final StringBuilder sBuild2 = new StringBuilder();
            
            try {
                String userJsonAsString = convert your JSON to string and store in var;
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject output = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(userJsonAsString);
            try {
                
                JSONArray docs = (JSONArray) output.get("users");
                Iterator<Object> iterator = docs.iterator();
                
                
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    JSONObject userEleObj = (JSONObject)iterator.next();
                    JSONArray nestedIdArray = (JSONArray) userEleObj.get("identities");
                    Iterator<Object> nestIter = nestedIdArray.iterator();
                     
                    while (nestIter.hasNext()) {
                        JSONObject identityEleObj = (JSONObject)nestIter.next(); 
                        identityEleObj.keySet().stream().forEach(key -> sBuild2.append(identityEleObj.get(key) + ","));
                        userEleObj.keySet().stream().forEach(key -> {
                            if (StringUtils.equals((CharSequence) key, "identities")) {
                                sBuild.append(sBuild2.toString());
                                sBuild2.replace(0, sBuild2.length(), "");
                            } else {
                                sBuild.append(userEleObj.get(key) + ","); 
                            }
                                
                        });
                         
                    }
                    sBuild.replace(sBuild.lastIndexOf(","), sBuild.length(), "\n");  
                }
                
                System.out.println(sBuild);
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried you approach it worked! perfectly. thanks I am marking as answer

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse the json and just store the "leafs" in map.
Note: array of primitives will turn into the last value in the array with this approach, but that's what you described :)

Something like this:

```
void flatJson() throws JSONException {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(userJsonAsString); // this is your input
    Map<String, Object> flatKeyValue = new HashMap<>();
    readValues(object, flatKeyValue);
    System.out.println(new JSONObject(flatKeyValue)); // this is flat
}

void readValues(JSONObject object, Map<String, Object> json) throws JSONException {
    for (Iterator it = object.keys(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        String key = (String) it.next();
        Object next = object.get(key);
        readValue(json, key, next);
    }
}

void readValue(Map<String, Object> json, String key, Object next) throws JSONException {
    if (next instanceof JSONArray) {
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) next;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); ++i) {
            readValue(json, key, array.opt(i));
        }
    } else if (next instanceof JSONObject) {
        readValues((JSONObject) next, json);
    } else {
        json.put(key, next);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: Not sure what link you are after ?

Comment: I was trying to read you code, I am not sure about calling structure, and where I am feeding my JSON string in the code. I am trying to write a code which will follow a main() method type of structure. I am not sure how will I embed your code in mine.

Comment: I added comments to make it easier to follow, you can copy-paste the code and put content of `flatJson` into main method to run it.

Comment: I tried your solution, it is giving me a flat JSON but its is not giving output for both users, just one user ( the last user it got) i think some problem with iterator.

Comment: can you suggest why it's taking only the last entry from the array, I gave that example for one, I am trying to debug and get all the entries from my json and not just the last user.

Comment: The description is misleading  - so you’d like to flatten but on per-user basis within the top level array ? On the description you showed 1 user out of the array of 2. If you’d like to get each user flattened then apply the flattening operation to each user instead of the top level array: iterate over users in JSON array and flatten them separately using the exact approach I implemented in the comment

Comment: okay, but that description was just a sample of how a flatten JSON was supposed to look, my apologies if it seemed misleading.

Comment: No worries, then to use the solution I gave you just need to apply it to the each user in the array individually and you'll get them flattened separately. 
Iterate over all users and for each user apply "flatJson" method - just make it accept JSONObject as param instead of it read the JSON object itself.

Comment: Actually I made a mistake when describing question, if you see the JSON which I provided above, I made a serious mistake where you might have seen "users" wrapper for each object, but it ACTUALLY like one "users" wrapper for all the users, I have updated the question. Can you check and tell if your logic is applicable to the current JSON as well?

Comment: meanwhile I will try your suggestion.